# Send login link in email to registered users

Tags: users

On my Drupal 6 website, there are around 400 users registered by site admin and none of then know that they are registered on the site. Now I want to increase the number of registered users but in a secure manner.

I want the registered users to be able to invite at most 5 people whom they think are the most eligible. This is very easy and has been done.

The problem is that to invite new users, the current users will need to login and I dont want them to know their username and password as they will be given to them later.

So the only solution that remains is that I send them a login link in their e-mail so that they can click on the link and get automatically logged in so they can invite 5 other people of their choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Login one time](http://drupal.org/project/login_one_time) module for this.

> Login one time provides the ability to email one-time login links to
>   users. You can also choose the pages they will land on.

I would imagine that the users might be able to change their own paswords after using this one time link.  To prevent this, you should be able to use the [Edit own user account permission](http://drupal.org/project/edit_own_user_account_permission) module.

> This module manage edit permissions to the name, mail and password
>   profile filed. You can manage permissions to the other profile
>   entities by other admin menu settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I acually dont want the users to know or change their username and password. I want them to login only through the link sent to them in email.

Comment: Yes, the answer still stands then!  The second part about password changing is just in case you have some cunning users!  But the login one time module should work for you!

Comment: but i am already using the modulw Logintoboggan. Should that clash with this new module suggested by you. I have too many modules installed and my site is already very slow.

Comment: If you want to be able to send out one-time login e-mails - which is what your question asked - then the mentioned module is your best bet.  I'd just be concerned that once users have logged in with their one time link, they could change their passwords and access the things you don't want them too.  A combination of those two modules will disallow this.  Don't forget you can always remove them once this part of the project is over.  A slow site could also be down to other things (caching etc)